# What to modify this regex to accept this URL in Django?

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I have a Django URL like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<category_id>\w+)/beginner/$', views.beginner, name='beginner')
```

This regex accepts URL like these:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/quiz/grammar/beginner/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/quiz/vocabulary/beginner/
```

But the URL with `'-'` is not accepted:

```
# This URL is not accepted
http://127.0.0.1:8000/quiz/business-english/beginner/
```

How can I modify this regex to accept URL with `'-'`

Comment: Maybe (.+) url(r'^(?P<category_id>.+)/beginner/$', views.beginner, name='beginner')

Answer (score 5):

Better is to replace `\w+` with `[\w-]+` Now it will match words and `-`

says : match words `\w` or `-` 1 or more times

Your Django url looks like

```
url(r'^(?P<category_id>[\w-]+)/beginner/$', views.beginner, name='beginner')
```

Answer (score 1):

`\w` matches letters, digits and `_`,  not `-`.

Replace `\w` with `[-\w]`:

```
url(r'^(?P<category_id>[-\w]+)/beginner/$', views.beginner, name='beginner')
```

Comment: Did `url(r'^(?P<category_id>[-\w])/beginner/$', views.beginner, name='beginner')` but no I am getting URL not found for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/quiz/vocabulary/beginner/` too.

Comment: @user2032220, Keep `+`.